# Can't send BytesIO to Telegram bot:

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Situation.
I need to create in-memory csv file and send it to bot.
According to this [article](https://medium.com/@okhlopkov/dont-save-a-file-on-disk-to-send-it-with-telegram-bot-d7cd591fec2d) and bot documentation I assume I can send csv files. Difference: i use another api wrapper: [telebot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI). According to docs it also allows to send binary files.
So I am trying to test this like that:

```
def test_buf():
    import csv
    import io
    test_data = [[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]]

    # csv module can write data in io.StringIO buffer only
    s = io.StringIO()
    csv.writer(s).writerows(test_data)
    s.seek(0)

    # python-telegram-bot library can send files only from io.BytesIO buffer
    # we need to convert StringIO to BytesIO
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    # extract csv-string, convert it to bytes and write to buffer
    buf.write(s.getvalue().encode())
    buf.seek(0)

    # set a filename with file's extension
    buf.name = 'test_data.csv'
    return buf
```

And then

```
csv_output = test_buf()
bot.send_document(chat_id, csv_output, caption='Caption_text')
```

And I get an error:

```
"ApiTelegramException occurred, args=("A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400 Description: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 7",)
```

What do i do wrong? Maybe I don't fully understand difference between BytesIO and binary format? If it's different how to transform bytesio to binary **in-memory** so i could send data
For now I can send file but without telebot library:

```
requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TELEGRAM_TOKEN}/sendDocument',
                data={"chat_id": chat_id, "caption": 'caption_text'},
                files={'document': csv_output})
```

So I do not understand what an issue with library. It like I sure that I just don't understand some basic stuff.

Comment: Have you tried sending the contents of the ByteBuffer instead of the object itself? `buf.getvalue()` . a link to the function's documentation would be helpful, the general readme isn't very helpful

Comment: @fibonachoceres using buf.get_value() also trigger error